# How can I get a list of NFTs that I have minted?

Tags: reactjs, api, ethereum, polygon, nft

I am building Social Media for NFT.

I would like to get a list of NFTs minted in the past by a particular user in Ethereum and Polygon Chain. It does not have to be currently held.
Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You write this function in your smart contract

```
function getOwnedNfts() public view returns(NftItem[] memory){
    uint ownedItemsCount=ERC721.balanceOf(msg.sender);
    NftItem[] memory items= new NftItem[](ownedItemsCount);
    for (uint i=0; i<ownedItemsCount; i++){
      // when user owns a token, I keep track of them in mapping instead of array
     // It is saving the tokens of user in order
      uint tokenId=tokenOwnerByIndex(msg.sender, i);
      NftItem storage item=_idToNftItem[tokenId];
      items[i]=item;
    }
    return items;
  }
```

- this is `ERC721.balanceOf`

  ```
  function balanceOf(address owner) public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
            require(owner != address(0), "ERC721:zero address");
            return _balances[owner];
        }
  ```

When you call `_mint` function, the address who has minted is added to `_balance`

- this is `tokenOwnerByIndex`

  ```
   function tokenOwnerByIndex(address owner,uint index) public view returns(uint){
        require(index<ERC721.balanceOf(owner), "Index out of bounds");
        return _ownedTokens[owner][index];
      }
  ```

`_ownedTokens` is a mapping:

```
//{address:{1:tokenId-1,2:tokenId-2}}
  mapping(address=>mapping(uint=>uint)) private _ownedTokens;
```

then in front-end, after setting up provider and contract, you just call this function:

```
    const myNfts = await contract!.getOwnedNfts();
```

Comment: What if user sells his tokens? You need to keep track of it. Let's assume that I have 3 tokens and I've sold first one. Now in the _ownedTokens['my address'] you need to move second index to first, and third to second.